# How to open a form by Clicking on a specific Row in a ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to open a new form by clicking on a row in a ListView and pass the NoteId that is listed in the specific Row to the new Form, can anyone help please?

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I have only been programming since last month and my research proved fruitless :(

```
        private void populatingMainList()
    {

        List<Note> getAllNotes = GetAllNotes();

        lstMain.Items.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < getAllNotes.Count; i++)
        {
            lstMain.FullRowSelect = true;
            string _note;
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(_note = getAllNotes[i].NoteComplete.ToString());
            if (_note == "True")
            {
                lvi.Text = "";
                lvi.Checked = true;                    
            }
            else
            {
                lvi.Text = "";
                lvi.Checked = false;
            }
            lvi.SubItems.Add(getAllNotes[i].NoteTitle);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(getAllNotes[i].NoteDot.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
            lvi.SubItems.Add(getAllNotes[i].NoteNote);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(getAllNotes[i].NoteId.ToString());

            lstMain.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
    }

    private void lstMain_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //I believe that some sort of code that retrieve NoteId from the specific Row must be added here.

        if (_list == true)
        {
            frmSticky StickyForm = new frmSticky(_currentUser, _noteid);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void lstMain_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lst = sender as ListView;
    _noteid = lst.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3];

    if (_list == true)
    {
        frmSticky StickyForm = new frmSticky(_currentUser, _noteid);

    }
}
```

Comment: Basically I copied your code and it is giving me the "cannot convert to string" error, fine. I set the _noteId_ to _ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem_ and I converted it to string but when I run it, it's displaying  "ListViewSubItem: {}" which I want to get rid of so that than I can create a method to call the note and display it.

Comment: If you want the value, use Text property like:

_noteid.Text

Answer (score 0):

You can use a contextmenustrip for your listview and then add a button on it with function to open the form you are trying to.

1.Find ContextMenuStrip and add it to your application from toolbox.

[image]

2.Add it to your listview as shown in the image below.

[image]

3.Select the contextmenu you added and create a new button by clicking on "Type here".

[image]

4.Double click that button on your contextmenu and write the code you want to execute when you click on that button on contextmenu from listview.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How do you get the contextmenustrip? It's not listed in my toolbox.

Comment: It must be there search in toolbox search and assign that contextmenu to your listview by selecting the listview and look for contextmenu option in the listview settings and assign that contextmenu to it.

Comment: @PuppyD13 i have added images to my answer to make it easier for you.